# Adaptive filtering

Tags: lowpass-filter, denoising, adaptive-filters

I want to mention upfront that I'm not very experienced in this field.

I have a signal $u(k)$ that I get from a black box simulation (sampled irregularly). The signal looks like this:

[image]

The blue signal has small frequency oscillations that i want to remove. The orange curve was obtained by fitting a polynomial on the whole dataset.

My goal is to obtain a smooth estimate of the blue signal in real-time (streaming data) and then compute its derivative. Is it possible to obtain something as smooth as the orange curve ?

If so, can you suggest some commonly used methods ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to DSP.SE! Does [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88190/63398) answer your question?

Comment: Search this site and the internet for Savitzky-Golay filters. There's also a Savitzky-Golay differentiator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have few options:

1. On Line Least Squares
   You may use the [Sequential Least Squares](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/56670/128) (MATLAB Code available in the link).
   This will give you exactly what you got using the polynomial model.
   Since it is a polynomial model, you will be able to calculate the derivative on line as well.
2. [Savitzky Golay Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter)
   Those filter with pre defined coefficients approximate the polynomial Least Squares solution locally.
   They also have a variant to calculate the derivative on line.
   Since they are online they are even more sensitive to outliers (Locally) than the global Least Squares.
3. [Kalman Filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/21598)
   You may use the Kalman Filter to have online estimation both of the smooth curve and its local derivative.